# Getting ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe

I get this error

```
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

My code is

```
all_columns=[ col  for col, dt in y.dtypes.items() if dt == 'object']
df[all_columns] = df[all_columns].astype(str)
```

I have some columns which are in dict format. So I want to convert all those columns into proper string data type.
Please tell me why I am getting this error, I am using the same column list on both sides, right?

**> Answer : Duplicates columns in the dataframe resulted in this type of
error. There are two columns with the same name.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Hummarabi I started going step by step by taking 10 columns at a time and print the column names which are of type object

```
for col in y.columns[1:10]:
    if y[col].dtypes == 'object':
#          y[col] = y[col].astype(str)
        print(col)
```

So I got this error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

during the y.columns[50:60] columns
So I printed the columns by `y[y.columns[60:70]].head(80)` and to my surprise I saw that there are two columns with the same name. ('error','error')
So I dropped one of the column and ran and now everything works fine and I get no errors now.
But this type of manual checking is bit cumbersome for extremely large data though.
But one observation is     **ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().**

---

> ***occurs when there are duplicates in the data***

---

Comment: Nice job debugging that, and thanks for pointing out the issue with duplicates

Answer (score 2):

Try this simpler iteration, since it looks like something is going wrong with your list comprehension.  Given the issue you describe in your comments, do something like print the name of the column as you iterate, to see which column is crashing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'TEXT': ['hello there', 'python fun', np.nan, '']})

print(df.dtypes)
# TEXT    object
# dtype: object

for col in df.columns:
    print(col)
    if df[col].dtype == 'object':
        df[col] = df[col].astype(str)
        print('converted', col)

print(df.dtypes)
# TEXT    object
# dtype: object
```

Alternatively, try this list comprehension to get all object columns at once, maybe your list comprehension is the issue:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'TEXT1': ['hello there', 'python fun', np.nan, ''],
                   'TEXT2': ['hi', 'bye', np.nan, ''],
                   'not text': [1, 2, 3, 4]})

obj_cols = [col for col in df.columns if df[col].dtype == 'object']

df[obj_cols] = df[obj_cols].astype(str)
```

Comment: I get this error now : ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Could you post a sample of your df?  I can't reproduce that error. I'll edit my answer to show a toy example.

Comment: It has 147 columns. This same error is not occurring if I use some 4 or 5 columns

Comment: Check some of the columns at a time maybe, e.g., print the col name if it converts to astype(str) without crashing

Comment: It is working fine for fewer number of columns.

Comment: I tried this :-y = [y[col_name].astype(str) for col_name in y.columns if y[col_name].dtypes == 'object']
this gives me the same error ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Why are you assigning a list to y?  y appears to be a dataframe.  When I use what you wrote, y = [0    hello there
1     python fun
2            nan
3               
Name: TEXT, dtype: object]   Use the code that I provided instead.